# websocket automatically trying to decode broken string into utf8 and failing. Could not decode a text frame as UTF-8

Tags: javascript, websocket, browser, utf-8

```
var ip = 'wss://173-255-221-28.devast.io/';

websocket = new window.WebSocket(ip);

websocket.binaryType = "arraybuffer";

websocket.onmessage = function(event) {

    console.log("aa");
};

websocket.onopen = function(event) {
    websocket.send('[30,"3056nick85j2ktlkH54a","40555", -1, 0, "JOCKO WILLINKS", 0, 0, 0]');
};
```

I'm receiving a broken string that cannot be decoded with utf8 because it has unsupported characters.

**I have zero access to the server.**

**I heard browsers automatically close websocket connections if non utf8 encoded characters are found.**

The problem is from the server which I don't have access to, from this code, I should get a message with array of player nicknames in the server, and some people glitched unsupported nicknames and now `onmessage` doesn't even work

Similar thing happens to web chatrooms where some user sends a complicated unsupported message and all the chatroom will disconnect

That's how the bytes look in raw in python, 120 items of nicknames.

[image]

`"\\u000b \\r\\t\\n\\f"` is probably the culprit

Using `arraybuffer` to get raw binary in JS won't work still, because it will automatically convert to string.

How can I ignore this error, or get the data without error and from there manually fix it? I need websockets for low input delay.

Comment: Can you split the string, and turn it into an array? Then you could loop through it, parse what you can, and try and fix what you can't parse.

Comment: @FiddlingAway
browsers doesnt support non utf8 encoded websocket messages, so im getting an error instantly, the problem is i cant even access the data that was sent to me in any way

Comment: in equevalent script in python it parsed the byte data with decoding error but i can access it, on js i cant